# Autobiographer badge's tooltip cut-off on "Profile" tab

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page, tooltips

This is the Autobiographer badge's tooltip in [my account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/189165/trejder?tab=badges) (`Activity` tab):

[image]

And this is from [another user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/278624/blaketm)'s profile (`Profile` tab):

[image]

And here comes an example from [yet another user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/276281/adv12)'s profile (`Profile` tab as well):

[image]

Looks like a bug. May affect other badges and may have nothing to do with tab.